# Adding current date in Jenkins email

Tags: email, jenkins

I am sending an email after my build in jenkins job and I am using HTML for construction of email content, now I want to be able to add - current date in 'DEFAULT CONTENT' i.e Email content and also into the 'Subject' line of the email.

However 
In case of 'DEFAULT CONTENT' - without using Javascript I am unable to find a way.

and I have no idea how can I achieve this in 'Subject' line of the email.

Any help ?!

Comment: What plugin are you using to send the mails?

Comment: In 'POST-BUILD ACTIONS' > 'Editable Email Notification'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Build Timestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Timestamp+Plugin) to retrieve the build timestamp and export it to an environment variable and then you can use the variable in your e-mail subject line.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible without installing any plugin, but be sure that your jenkins instance is running the right date, to be sure type **date** in your shell.

Then go on your jenkins job

in **Execute shell** panel :

date > timestamp.txt

Then in the **Editable Email Notification** panel , in Default Content section :

${FILE,path="./timestamp.txt"}